# vb6-connecting to a remote server with mysql

Tags: mysql, vb6, odbc, connection-string

I have a VB6 project where would be adding data to database and querying it later. I have a method `updateDB` for updating the database with fields:

```
Function UpdateDB()
Dim DBCon As ADODB.Connection
Dim DBCmd As ADODB.Command
Dim dbrecset As ADODB.Recordset


Set DBCon = New ADODB.Connection
DBCon.CursorLocation = adUseClient
DBCon.ConnectionString = "Driver = {MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server =myHosting; Port = 3306;Database=myDB;UID=myUID;PWD=12345;Option=16427;"

DBCon.Open
Set dbrecset = New ADODB.Recordset
With DBCmd
.ActiveConnection = DBCon
.CommandText = "UPDATE vbtest SET Name = '" & Text1.Text & "'," _
& "Serial = '" & Text2.Text & "'," _
& "WHERE Key = '" & Text3.Text & "' AND Name IS NULL"
.CommandType = adCmdText
End With

With dbrecset
.CursorType = adOpenStatic
.CursorLocation = adUseClient
.LockType = adLockOptimistic
.Open DBCmd
End With

dbrecset.Close
DBCon.Close

End Function
```

This function gives the following error at run-time.

[image: VBError]

**EDIT**:I have tried it by using versions 3.51/5.1/5.2 of the ODBC drivers

What am I doing wrong? Been stuck around for days now. Please help

Comment: You have installed the (32bit) driver?

Comment: Should have written that. Yes i have.

Comment: And it's definitely the 3.51 driver? (as opposed to 5.x)

Comment: FYI, connectionstrings.com shows the 3.51 driver conn string to be: `Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;
User=myUsername;Password=myPassword;Option=3;` (which differs from yours in UID/PWD). I'd recommend getting rid of the extra spaces, too.

Comment: Well, I have even tried those. I have the 5.2 driver and have put that in the connection strong too. That wouldn't work either.

Comment: You have the 5.2 driver, but you're requesting the 3.51 driver in your code example above?

Comment: Take a look at: http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-odbc-5-2/

Comment: I'm guessing you want to use this conn string: `Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2 ANSI Driver};Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;
User=myUsername;Password=myPassword;Option=3;`

Comment: @LynnCrumbling This is not working.

I have tried the code with 3.51/5.1/5.2 Drivers. Same error.